# Chrome extension jQuery post/get do not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am learning about chrome extensions and even jQuery works in my extension post/get methods do not.

For example I inject this to every page:

```
// this works, so jQuery works  
$( "a" ).each(function( index ) {
  $ (this).hide();
});

$.post( "http://mywebsite", { n: "John", l: "j" });
```

However, post method is does call the website. If I add same `$.post(...)` code into a regular html page it works just fine.

Is there are some kind of limitations for chrome extensions that I am not aware or I am simply missing something here? Thank you.

EDIT:

I now noticed that it only works if URL starts with http and does not work with https, even I have permissions set to:

```
"permissions": [
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
]
```

That is very strange.

Comment: How are you injecting the code into pages?

Answer (score 1):

i think you forgot to put your website on the permission in your manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "My extension",
  ...
  "permissions": [
    "http://www.your-url.com/"
  ],
  ...
}
```

Then after modify your manifest.json don't forgot to reload it from the extension page.